# jQuery Ajax: FormData is returning 403 error for base64 data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a base64 image data through FormData using jQuery ajax.
But it failed with 403 error. But If I remove base64 data from input then it works perfectly fine.

That's strange.

Even If I enter just this value in input "data:image/jpeg;base64" then it will fail with 403 error.

So is it really possible to upload base64 string ( image ) using FormData() ? if yes then why did not this work?

My code:

```
<script>
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
formData.append('base64Img', base64);
var url  = "http://www.example.com";
var type  = "POST";
$.ajax({data:formData, type:type, url:url, processData:false, cache:false, contentType:false});
</script>
```

Comment: Where you trying to upload? What code is on far end? Maybe your endpoint expects smth. more than just `base64` data? Show some of your code where you are composing that `FormData()` request.

Comment: I added code. Please check

Comment: 403 is FORBIDDEN so why are you not being authorized? Do you have access to the logs? Is there something in mod_security or whatever your settings that does not like files?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.
Actually everything is fine in my code.

Issue was with my hosting. Hosting company resolved my issue.

Thanks